# Cannot boot Ubuntu 16.10 after resizing /boot with GParted (EFI, LVM, and LUKS encryption)

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption

I have been trying to recover my system after having done this, but without much success. I've tried several times to use boot-repair following the instructions, but on boot up, I never get the prompt to decrypt the volume.

This is the output from boot-repair on one of the attempts: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23321038

After that attempt, I still couldn't boot. I booted through recovery and was eventually able to get to the UI. In there, I tried reinstalling grub and updating to 16.10 in hopes that it would repair the issue, but unfortunately, after restart, the issue remained.

Attempted to fix by chrooting and re-installing grub, but still haven't had much luck. Let me know what outputs are needed. I can't boot into the system, but have a LiveUSB I can use.

EDIT: Here is a link to the latest run of boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23322135/

I am using 15.10 since my 16.10 usb is having issues booting at the moment.

EDIT: Hard disk is RAID (Intel) and GPT partitioned.

Comment: your hard disk partition is MBR or GPT format?

Comment: @Cloud I added that info to the question

Answer (score 0):

If I were not misunderstanding your post, I think your problem is boot loader missing problem. Because I face this problem when I try to install ubuntu 16.04 LTS with along side with windows 10.

At this time, I try to install ubuntu from my usb memory stick. I used [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create nest in usb. And I choose the the wrong partition scheme as `MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI` because I already format my hard disk to GPT format.

So, when I try to install ubuntu from this usb drive everything is fine until it reach to install `grub`. When installation process reach `grub` installation, I got error and installation process is crush and when I try to boot, I never seen the ubuntu boot loader.

So, I try to repair `grub` a lot of times and also used ubuntu boot repair tools. But nothing works. It still the same error.

After I read a lot of post, I understand my problem is missing boot loader and it because of I choose wrong disk format when I create nest in usb.

My usb nest format is `MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI` and my hard disk format is only `GPT` format. So, the format is wrong and it happened boot loader missing problem.

After that I recreate nest in usb with [Rufus] by using `GPT partition scheme for UEFI` only. This time when I install ubuntu again, everything is fine and no boot loader problem again.

I think my solution will help some idea for you.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Currently, I make sure that I boot the USB from UEFI, so that is not the issue.